# Display two column table on smartphone

Tags: gui-design, layout, ios, tables

I've been somewhat struggling on how to display a two column table on a smartphone (iOS app specifically).

My said that they would like something other than a boring `UITableView` to display the data. I told them that while it maybe boring it is the most user friendly option and most practical. That being said, I decided that I would sexy up a `UITableView` in hopes that they would realize it's the best option.

Here is the structure of the data: 
[image]

---

My biggest issue is trying to include the title of the columns into the view. Here is what I was thinking:

Have the view work similar to the Twitter app, where you can swipe in between tables. The first view list by the "Commonly Prescribed Medicines", the second view list sorts by "What is Treated".

**"Commonly Prescribed Medicines"**
[image]

**"What is Treated"**
[image]

As you can see at the top, the two little •• to denote that the view is horizontally scrollable.

My only issue with this is that it seems like I'm overcomplicating it. I don't see any benefit in being able to switch between the different data views. It's such a small subset of data that you can easily digest it all on a single screen.

Please shoot holes in my idea.

Comment: It does seem overcomplicated, as you say. If the aim is to sort the list by either the drug name or the symptom, it is surely easier to allow sorting on the columns rather than having two separate tables and swiping between them?

Comment: I would agree, the issue that I had with that was how to display both the column names. I saw swiping between tables as a way to show one column name at a time. Thoughts?

Comment: I guess we should take a step back and ask who is using this and why? Are there two very separate user groups?

Comment: It is primarily physicians in the age range of 35-65. The use cases from the customer is that they would be using this for quick reference so the data needs to be clearly displayed. It also needs to be uncomplicated since it's an older user group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of sticking to a 2-column layout, I would suggest going for a list based layout as shown in the mock-up below:

[image]

In this layout, the Medicine name can be the title and the condition it treats can be shown as tags under the medicine name. Furthermore, if the user wishes to search all medicines for a particular condition, he can just click on the tag to filter all medicines that are used to treat that particular sickness as shown in the second mock-up.

In addition to this, it is always good practice to provide a search box on top of any list with numerous records.

*Note: [Mock-up link](http://framebox.org/sEVP)*

Comment: I like the filter aspect! Very nice, thanks for your help.